# Reverse for 'update_laptop' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update_laptop/(?P<laptop_id>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: django

I am building an Inventory system and want to add update functionality. but unfortunately, it is not working.

Please help me with this code error.

views.py:

```py
def update_laptop(request, laptop_id):  # function for updation of laptops.
    update = Laptop.objects.get(pk=laptop_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LaptopForm(request.POST, instance=update)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('laptop')
    form = LaptopForm(request.POST)
    context = {
        'forms': form, 'header': 'Laptop'
    }
    return render(request, 'device/update_laptop.html', context)
```

update_laptop.html:

```html
{% extends 'device/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <form action="" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <h3>Add {{ header }}:</h3>
      {{ forms|crispy }}
      <a href="{% url 'update_laptop' forms.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-info"type="submit">Update</a>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py:

```py
path('update_laptop/<str:laptop_id>/', views.update_laptop, name='update_laptop')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forms` has no `.id`, hence that will not work. You can pass the `laptop_id` to the view, or obtain this from the `form.instance.id`.

The construction of the form is however wrong, since in the case of a GET request, you should not pass `request.POST`, but you can nevertheless pass the `instance=update`.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def update_laptop(request, laptop_id):
    laptop = get_object_or_404(Laptop, pk=laptop_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LaptopForm(request.POST, instance=laptop)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('laptop')
    form = LaptopForm(instance=laptop)
    context = {
        'forms': form,
        'header': 'Laptop'
    }
    return render(request, 'device/update_laptop.html', context)
```

In the template, you should make a submit button. By using a link, you will make a GET request, and thus not update the object:

```
<form action="{% url 'update_laptop' forms.instance.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Add {{ header }}:</h3>
    {{ forms|crispy }}
    <button "type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: can I apply same kind of code for other devices? like desktops, mobiles etc

Comment: @MuhammadAbubakar: normally yes. of course with another form, model, and view.

Comment: yes got your note as well. thanks for sharing your knowledge.